# Generating summary scores and dealing with missingness for two versions of a questionnaire (in R)

Tags: r

I am trying to create summary scores from item scores for a questionnaire. Only individuals who meet our criteria of maximum number of missing items can receive a summary score. The rest receive NA.

This is what I have so far:

```
df.measure <- data.frame(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5,item6, item7, item8) # data frame with relevant items
missing.items <- apply(df.measure, 1, function (x) sum(is.na(x))) # sum of missing items
summary_score <- ifelse(missing.items<=2, rowMeans(df.wd_m7, na.rm=TRUE), NA)  # if missing items less than or equal to 2, give row mean. If more than 2, return NA 
summary_score <- as.numeric(summary_score) * 8 # summary score = mean item score * number of items
```

The issue is that there are two versions of the questionnaire. For version 1, I can allow missingness of 2 or less items. For version 2, I can allow missingness of only 1 item.

I tried the following but it did not work.

```
summary_score <- if(data$questionnaire.version == '1') {

  ifelse(missing.items<=2, rowMeans(df.measure, na.rm=TRUE), NA)
}

 else if(data$questionnaire.version == '2') {
 ifelse(missing.items<=1, rowMeans(df.measure, na.rm=TRUE), NA)

}
```

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double-nested ifelse statement worked:

```
summary_scores <- ifelse (data$questionnaire.version == "1", 
             ifelse(missing.items<=2, rowMeans(df.measure, na.rm=TRUE), NA) ,
             ifelse(missing.items<=1, rowMeans(df.measure, na.rm=TRUE), NA)
             )
```

Followed by:

```
summary_score <- as.numeric(summary_score) * 8
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have forgotten to wrap your if/else if statement with `{}`

```
summary_score <- {if(data$questionnaire.version == '1') {

 ifelse(missing.items<=2, rowMeans(df.measure, na.rm=TRUE), NA)
}

 else if(data$questionnaire.version == '2') {
  ifelse(missing.items<=1, rowMeans(df.measure, na.rm=TRUE), NA)

}}
```

The two first lines of your code work fine with this.

Comment: Thanks but it is still not working after wrapping the statement. I get the following errors:

    Error in if (data$questionnaire.version == "1") { :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
    In addition: Warning message:
    In if (data$questionnaire.version == "1") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Then the problem comes from your `data$questionnaire.version`. I assumed it was a simple integer. What do you get when you print it ?

Comment: It prints NA, 1 or 2 for each individual in the dataframe.

Comment: So questionnaire.version is part of your df.measure ?

Plus what are you looking for ? A global score over the questionnaire or a score for each version of the questionnaire ? I suggest that you subset your data into two distinct sets (one for each version) and compute mean for each of them.

Eventually, you compute a weighted average (based on the number of lines of each set) if you want to merge results.

Comment: Update: problemo has been resolved. Thanks for your help!
I found that the combination of ifelse and else and if was probably problematic. I've used a nested ifelse statement and it has worked.